# Special characters in column name bad?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know if there are any performance or technical issues that can arise from using special characters to name db columns.

For example, instead of "PhoneNumber", I would use "Phone#".

I know that permitted characters in quoted identifiers include the full Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane. But in terms of standards, performance and possible technical issues, can this cause a problem ?

Thanks

Comment: I personally wouldn't do it.  I'd use Number or No instead of #.  I'd refrain from using anything that would make it hard to write queries against.  SQL is not a front end.  That's what your GUI is for.

Comment: see here [Rules for Regular Identifiers](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/154c19c4-95ba-4b6f-b6ca-479288feabfb/characters-that-are-not-allowed-in-table-name-column-name-in-sql-server-?forum=databasedesign)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here [Rules for Regular Identifiers](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/154c19c4-95ba-4b6f-b6ca-479288feabfb/characters-that-are-not-allowed-in-table-name-column-name-in-sql-server-?forum=databasedesign)

The first character must be one of the following:

- A letter as defined by the Unicode Standard 3.2. The Unicode
  definition of letters includes Latin characters from a through z,
  from A through Z, and also letter characters from other languages.
- The underscore (_), at sign (@), or number sign (#).